# Table of two tabulars first one shorter than second one

Tags: tables

I have the following table that consists of two tabulars. How can I align these two? Currently the first one is stretched, but only the last column. I would like the columns to be evenly distributed on the whole width, similar to the second (larger) tabular.

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,foot=1cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, longtable, tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test results}
\begin{tabular}{lrlrlrl}
Object 1 x Object 2 &   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.34345} & & Object 3 x Object 4 &   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.8794} \\
Test performance & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.33434} & & Test performance & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.1231} \\
Items involved & & Item A, Item B & & Items involved & & Item A, Item B \\
Score achieved & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.9999} & & Score achieved & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.6784} \\
Test result positive? & & yes  &  & Test result positive? & & yes \\
\hline
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccccc}
\hline
Probability d1 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d2 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d3 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d4 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d5 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d6 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d7 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d8 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d9 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d10 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d11 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d12 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d13 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d14 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d15 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d16 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabular}%

\end{table}%
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different variants with slightly different alignment and spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,foot=1cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, longtable, tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
%\savebox{\mybox}{\parbox{4cm}{\lorem}}
%\showthe\wd\mybox 

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test results}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{14}{@{}c@{}}{
\begin{tabular}{lrlclrl}
Object 1 x Object 2 &   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.34345} & & Object 3 x Object 4 &   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.8794} \\
Test performance & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.33434} & & Test performance & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.1231} \\
Items involved & & Item A, Item B & & Items involved & & Item A, Item B \\
Score achieved & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.9999} & & Score achieved & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.6784} \\
Test result positive? & & yes  &  & Test result positive? & & yes \\
\end{tabular}}\\
\hline
Probability d1 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d2 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d3 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d4 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d5 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d6 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d7 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d8 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d9 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d10 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d11 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d12 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d13 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d14 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d15 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d16 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\
%\end{tabular}%

\end{table}%
\end{landscape}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test results}
\begin{tabular*}{0.85\linewidth}{@{}lrlc@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{\extracolsep{\tabcolsep}}rl@{}}
\hline
Object 1 x Object 2 &   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.34345} & & Object 3 x Object 4 &   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.8794} \\
Test performance & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.33434} & & Test performance & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.1231} \\
Items involved & & Item A, Item B & & Items involved & & Item A, Item B \\
Score achieved & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.9999} & & Score achieved & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.6784} \\
Test result positive? & & yes  &  & Test result positive? & & yes \\
\end{tabular*}\\
\begin{tabular*}{0.85\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccccccccccccc@{}}
\hline
Probability d1 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d2 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d3 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d4 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d5 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d6 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d7 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d8 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d9 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d10 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d11 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d12 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d13 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d14 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
Probability d15 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.123 \\
Probability d16 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 & 0.421 \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}%
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\hline`  I'd recommend using the lines from `booktabs`.

Comment: thanks that does the job. Sorry for late reply and acceptance, the site was down for me.